# How to make a magnetic feild intensity measurer app in Android - Java

Tags: java, android, apk

I'm new to Android Studio

I am trying to make a magnetic feild strength measuring app in android so I'm curious how can i convert the raw data from magnetic sensors in an device to Micro-Teslas μT

Comment: this raw data is already in μT, according to [DOCS (table. 1)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the values of all axis from the Magnetometer this will do it.
*(By default the values is in microTesla)*

```
public class MagnetActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            int x_value = event.values[0];
            int y_value = event.values[1];
            int z_value = event.values[2];
            // Do whatever you want to do with these magnetometer values.
    }
}
```